# How to store '>&2' in a variable

Tags: bash, io-redirection, variable-substitution

Similar question, but no answer: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

How to do the following in bash script?

```
error=">&2"
echo 'something went wrong' $error
```

instead of

```
echo 'something went wrong' >&2
```

Why?
Because if you typo it like `>2&`, it works normal but writes error messages to a file called `2`.

Comment: ok, I did it wrong way in my function. your solution works. Thanks!

Comment: @zevzek, more like `warn() { local IFS=' '; printf '%s\n' "$*" >&2; }` as `"$*"` joins args with the first character of `$IFS`. Or `warn() print -ru2 -- "$@"` in ksh/zsh. See also the `syserror` builtin in `zsh`'s `zsh/system` module.

Comment: I would *not* recommend `eval` for this -- it fixes this problem, but opens the door to a whole new and much messier bunch of problems. BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) does spot [`>2&` (and similar mistakes)](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2210), along with many others -- I recommend running your scripts through it as a general sanity-check.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks, also `sudo apt install shellcheck`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like they said in the comments, you don't, really.

Well, you could do that with `eval`, but you'd be in trouble with quoting/escaping everything *else* on that command line.

There's some things you can do with functions though: to run a given simple command under a redirection; or to just write a message to stderr:

```
#!/bin/bash
tostderr() {
        "$@" >&2
}

warn() {
        local IFS=" "
        printf "%s\n" "$*" >&2
}

tostderr printf "warning: %s\n" "something happened"

warn another thing to warn about
```

Emphasis on the *simple* command on the first one, it's not `eval` and  you can't have shell syntax within the command. E.g. in `tostderr foo | bar` it redirects the output of just `foo` (past the pipe to stderr), and `tostderr (foo | bar)` won't work.

---

If you were on zsh, and really wanted to, you could use a global alias to add the redirection (but some might think this is bordering on obfuscated coding):

```
#/usr/bin/zsh

alias -g TOSTDERR='>&2'
echo something bad happened TOSTDERR
```

---